# Is it possible to access the content of my answer for deleted question

Tags: support, status-completed

I have wrote answer for this [low quality question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36980/are-there-any-big-bang-theories-in-the-big-bang-theory/37024#37024) few months back, which got deleted. 
However now someone asked [other related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/why-was-the-big-bang-theory-given-that-name) , for which my answer can be useful. But now I don't know how to access that answer.

Is there any link or feature by which I can get that answer back.

I know the content of that answer, but i don't want to work on grammer and wording again as  i putted enough effort on same last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is your exact answer

> No. this show is not related to big bang theory. Its main characters
>   are scientists (2 physicists, an astrophysicist, and an engineer).
>   Most of the episodes are also made to sound like scientific theories
>   or terms. Not sure if the directors and producers ever revealed why
>   they named it so in any interviews, because I am not able to recall
>   any episode based on big bang theory.
>
> I can just speculate following reasons:
>
> 1. Maybe its because of the fact that those nerds (scientists) evolve slowly to become common man (or less nerdy).
> 2. Maybe someone wanted to exploit the meaning of "bang" , which Leonards seems to do with Penny in at least the initial episodes. In
>      fact, it was the main theme of the TV series when started, slowly
>      "Sheldon" become center character due to popularity.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Anyways what trouble you were getting in accessing chat?

Comment: I have not used much so didn't find  where to go.

Comment: @Panther [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) is our main chatroom, you just created the new one.